# Whirlpool fridge won't pass water through filter

Tags: water, refrigerator, filter

Our water was dispensing from our fridge very slow, so I replaced the filter. With the new filter the water is still slow. After some troubleshooting it seems water isn't even going through the filter.

1. With the filter removed the water dispenses with no problem.
2. With the filter in... the water is very slow and tastes like metal (unfiltered) just like it does with the filter out.
3. I can take the filter out, press and hold the small button inside the filtration system with a screw driver. This is what the filter pushes in when it's seated. Doing this I get the same results as number 2. I thought this would force water to come out the inlet.
4. If I remove the black o-rings on the filter... water comes gushing out of the filtration system. It seems this seats it correctly to use the filter, but the seal causes it to leak out.

Any ideas? I'm using the purple everydrop 1 filter. This was the same filter we were using before and it's supposed to work with our fridge model.

Comment: After messing with it some more. I figured out if put the filter in and push it in without closing the door it will work. However if I close the door fully it stops working.

Comment: This info should be in the text of the question, not in the comments — comments sometimes disappear; question text remains. Use the "Edit"  button below the question text.

Comment: If it is in warranty exercise that warranty it should not work like that. If out of warranty contact the manufacturer you may have an out of specification filter especially if the original filter worked.

Answer (score 1):

The hose running from filter to the door dispenser is blocked or just squished.

It usually runs from filter inside the fridge to the top left corner of the fridge then down inside the door to the dispenser. On some models you can access it from the top of the fridge where comes out and runs down to the dispenser in the door.

When replacing the filter you supposed to run two gallons or more to clean it up.